# Unable to run script to create queue and listener in ibm mq on linux

Tags: ibm-mq

I have script

```
define qlocal (ABCREQUEST)
define qlocal (XYZREQUEST)
```

in file `mqconfig.in`

I am running the `runmqsc` command in linux VM where I have installed IBM MQ version 9.2.0.0 as follows

```
sudo runmqsc VOLPAY_STDS < /home/adminuser/mqconfig.in
```

I see the following output:

```
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994,2020.
Starting MQSC for queue manager VOLPAY_STDS.
AMQ8135E: Not authorized.

No MQSC commands read.
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHBCP.png]

Comment: Run it as mqm not root.

Comment: I did it. It is saying that filename permission denied. I also applied chmod 777 to the file mqconfig.in.

Comment: Please copy and paste the current error instead of a screen shot into the question.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an MQ issue.  You are having a file permission issue.

```
sudo runmqsc VOLPAY_STDS < /home/adminuser/mqconfig.in
```

When you issue this command, runmqsc is now running under 'mqm' account and not your account.

> I also applied chmod 777 to the file mqconfig.in.

Ok. But 'mqm' does not have permission to access the directory tree '/home/adminuser/'.

You need to put your 'mqconfig.in' file in a directory that mqm has read access to.  If you don't know of one then use /tmp/ (or /var/tmp/ ) directory.